# how to draw the Shapes on the loaded offline map using java

Tags: paint, offline, shapes

I Developed the offline map using ArcGis ,I need to draw a Shapes on the map.I tried using paint () But I'm getting error .how can i achieve  this.Any suggestion is appreciable .

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/esri/samples/displayinformation/add_graphics_with_symbols